# Update a value in one column by a condition in another in csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file where there are columns Position and Quantity(Menge). I have to add copy of rows where(in my case it is Menge) Quantity >1 and I did it using :

```
file_to_check = file_to_check.loc[file_to_check.index.repeat(file_to_check.Menge)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

this works great, copied exactly as I wanted but I additionally have to update the Positions for them. 
For example :

```py
Position  Menge  Product
200        3       a
200        3       a
200        3       a
400        7       b
400        7       b
400        7       b
400        7       b
400        7       b
400        7       b
400        7       b
200        4       c
200        4       c
200        4       c
200        4       c
```

I want it to look like this

```py
Position  Menge   Product
200.1        3       a
200.2        3       a 
200.3        3       a
400.1        7       b
400.2        7       b
400.3        7       b
400.4        7       b
400.5        7       b
400.6        7       b
400.7        7       b
200.1        4       c
200.2        4       c
200.3        4       c
200.4        4       c
.
.
.
```

Afterwards I know I can change the Menge(Quantity) by using :

```
selected.loc[:, 'Menge'] = 1
```

I tried using for loop and loc as:

```py
counter=0
if selected.loc[selected.Menge >1]:
    counter=selected['Menge']
    i=1
    while counter>=1:
        selected['Pos.']+=i/10
        i+=1
        counter-=1
```

But I keep getting the error :

> 'ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'

I searched for the answer but nothing is really helping me. Some help is needed since I am pretty new to python and pandas.

So I edited my question. I have different Products but with some of them have same Pos. . How can I change for each product the Pos. and not add as if all of them are one product.as shown in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
In[75]:
df['Position'] = df['Position'] + df.groupby('Position')['Position'].rank(method='first')/10
df

Out[75]: 
   Position  Menge
0     200.1      3
1     200.2      3
2     200.3      3
3     400.1      7
4     400.2      7
5     400.3      7
6     400.4      7
7     400.5      7
8     400.6      7
9     400.7      7
```

So here I `groupby` on `'Position'` and call [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html#pandas.DataFrame.rank) with param `method='first'` so that equal values are ranked in order of appearance, this effectively ranks the values in order which is the same as a counter

Your error comes from this:

```
counter=selected['Menge']
```

and then doing a comparison using:

```
while counter>=1:
```

So the error is telling you that the it doesn't understand how to interpret a `Series` as doing `counter >=` returns a boolean Series, it wants a scalar boolean value to interpret. You'd have to iterate row-wise so you get a scalar value in order to interpret correctly, besides, you should look to avoid loops where possible as it's slow

**EDIT**

Based on your new data, you just `groupby` on multiple columns:

```
In[81]:
df['Position'] = df['Position'] + df.groupby(['Position','Menge'])['Position'].rank(method='first')/10
df

Out[81]: 
    Position  Menge Product
0      200.1      3       a
1      200.2      3       a
2      200.3      3       a
3      400.1      7       b
4      400.2      7       b
5      400.3      7       b
6      400.4      7       b
7      400.5      7       b
8      400.6      7       b
9      400.7      7       b
10     200.1      4       c
11     200.2      4       c
12     200.3      4       c
```

**EDIT**

OK, to handle the situation where you have more than 10 occurrences so that it avoids doing `201` for instance:

```
In[98]:
df['Position'] = (df['Position'].astype(str) + '.' + df.groupby(['Position','Menge'])['Position'].rank(method='first').astype(int).astype(str)).astype(float)
df

Out[98]: 
    Position  Menge Product
0      200.1      3       a
1      200.2      3       a
2      200.3      3       a
3      400.1      7       b
4      400.2      7       b
5      400.3      7       b
6      400.4      7       b
7      400.5      7       b
8      400.6      7       b
9      400.7      7       b
10     200.1      4       c
11     200.2      4       c
12     200.3      4       c
13     200.4      4       c
```

So this converts the output from `rank` first to an `int` as it produces a `float`, then casts to a `str` so we can just create a string e.g. `'200' + '.' + '1'` and then cast back to a `float` if necessary

Comment: So first thank you for your help. since I have to only add the numbers behind the "." (dot) i.e. if Menge >10 it should bring back 200.10 not 201.0 I did this then :
´´´python
selected['Pos.'] = numpy.where(selected['Menge']>99, selected['Pos.'] + selected.groupby('Pos.')['Menge'].rank(method='first')/1000,selected['Pos.'])´´´ and changed for 3 examples where Menge >99, >9 and >1. But I have another problem, there are different products with the same position. If there are 2 Products with the Pos. = 200 and diferent Menge I have to make sure that they are counted differently.

Comment: Update your question with your revised requirements, you should state clearly what you're trying to achieve and include all your requirements, sample data, desired result that shows all possibilities

Comment: thanks now I understand how it works, but I have a question , is there a possibility for me to somehow when adding additional number to not change the ones given. Like if Position = 200 and there are over 20 of them, that instead of 202 I get 200.20

Comment: See updated answer, basically you can cast to a str and construct the new ID from this

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Position':[200,200,200,400,400,400,400,400,400,400],'Menge':[3,3,3,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]})

for pos in df.Position.unique():    
    counter = 0.1
    for idx,row in df.iterrows():        
        if row['Position'] == pos:
            df.at[idx,'Position_1'] = df.at[idx,'Position']+counter
            counter+=0.1

df.drop(['Position'],axis=1,inplace=True)   
df.columns = ['Menge','Position']
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)



  Menge Position
0   3      200.1
1   3      200.2
2   3      200.3
3   7      400.1
4   7      400.2
5   7      400.3
6   7      400.4
7   7      400.5
8   7      400.6
9   7      400.7
```

Comment: I think @EdChum has a better and concise solution